# Make a like button for a Facebook object ID, not a URL?

Tags: facebook

Facebook's [docs on the like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) allow one to create a Like button for a URL.

However the docs also show that [likes are recorded against an object ID](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/), not a URL.

How can I make a like button for an ID (eg, '123456' ), rather than a URL?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764485/facebook-like-button-one-object-multiple-url-locale/16764826#16764826